# Access doesn't like my text file edited in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Can you pull data from a field in Notepad++ and create a new field?  I am a newbie at this.  I did get the EOL and extra spaces removed from a memo field and created two fields by pasting a symbol before the beginning of the field and import it to Access although that was easy because the field always begins with the same 3 letters - like XYZ and I used Find and Replace.  Ideally I would like to create a field for a key using field one and the first 14 characters of field two, both text fields.

Comment: Regular Expressions will do what you want, but it is not clear where you want the new field. Will it replace field 1, and will field 2 be cut? Or do you want a completely new field with duplicate information, and where? What if field 2 has fewer than 14 characters? [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) gives you everything you need to know, though it is a reference, not a tutorial: you will need to work out which RE standard your NP++ is using. I assume you are editing CSV files.